# Windows 7 Can't get Batch file to copy things properly

Tags: batch-file

I have no prior knowledge of coding or anything (Even though i mean to learn soon) and I'm only interested in this to help me back stuff up at the moment, and i can't get my batch file to copy things properly

I saw this online

```
@ECHO OFF

XCOPY "My desktop" "The file i'm backing it up to" /m /e /y

QUIT
```

It worked once, and now it just flashes a "0 files copied" and shuts off. It copies all the folders with their names but puts nothing in them and it's confusing me. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: From the XCOPY help file: **/M           Copies only files with the archive attribute set, turns off the archive attribute.**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the /m
like so:
   XCOPY "My desktop" "The file i'm backing it up to" /e /y

When you put /m it copies only file that the archive attribut set and then it turns off the attribut.
That is why the files won't copy the second time.